# Calculating the functional derivative of $\partial_\mu\phi$ with respect to $\phi$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Given $F_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi$, I need to find the functional derivative $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi}$. I am not familiar with the treatment of functional derivatives outside the context of finding Euler-Lagrange equations from the action and I'm struggling to apply various definitions of the functional derivative to this situation. What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trust you know that, in $d$ dimensions,
$$\frac{\delta \phi(x)}{\delta \phi(y)} = \delta^{(d)}(x-y).$$

This comes from the fact that given a function $f(x)$, we can treat it as if it were a functional by noticing that
$$f(x) = \int f(y) \delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^dy \tag{1}$$
and proceeding with the usual rules.

Since most of the remaining work has already been done by OP in the comments, I'll complete the answer. Notice we can write
$$F_\mu(x) = \int \partial^y_\mu \phi(y) \delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y,$$
where $\partial^y_\mu$ denote the derivative with respect to $y$. Integrating by parts, we see that
\begin{align}
F_\mu(x) &= \int \partial^y_\mu \phi(y) \delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y, \\
&= \oint_{\text{surface}} \phi(y) \delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}S_\mu - \int \phi(y) \partial^y_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y,
\end{align}
where we wrote the [volume integral of the gradient as a surface integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1958252/479421). Since the original integral was in the entire space, the surface over which we are integrating is at infinity, away from $y=x$. Since the delta will vanish everywhere apart from $y=x$, we get to

\begin{align}
F_\mu(x) &= - \int \phi(y) \partial^y_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y, \\
&= \int \phi(y) \partial^x_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y,
\end{align}
where we used the antisymmetry in $x \leftrightarrow y$ of $\delta^{(d)}(x-y)$ to write $\partial^x_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) = - \partial^y_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y)$. Now we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta F_\mu(x)}{\delta \phi(z)}
&= \int \frac{\delta \phi(y)}{\delta \phi(z)} \partial^x_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y, \\
&= \int \delta^{(d)}(y - z) \partial^x_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-y) \ \mathrm{d}^d y, \\
&= \partial^x_\mu\delta^{(d)}(x-z).
\end{align}

The choice of using different arguments in the functional derivative is for generality: we could consider $x=z$ just as we can consider $\delta^{(d)}(0)$ instead of the more general $\delta^{(d)}(x-z)$. However, this is less general and might lead to divergences if the functional derivative turns out to be a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), as is often the case.

Comment: So writing $F_\mu$ in the form of (1) gives $F_\mu(x) = \int \partial_\mu\phi(y) \delta(x-y) dy$. Attempting to integrate by parts, I get $F_\mu(x) = \phi - \int \phi(y) \delta'(x-y) dy$. Am I to assume the first term vanishes when evaluated over the interval (I am not sure how to argue this is true) or is this not correct?

Comment: @Hannah The surface term will be $\phi(y)\delta(x-y)$ evaluated at infinity, away from the point $x$. Since $\delta$ vanishes away from $y=x$, it will vanish and the surface term vanishes as well. As for the remaining term, just beware that you should get a four-derivative, so it should look like $\partial_\mu \delta$ instead of simply $\delta'$ (recall that $x$ and $y$ are points in a four-dimensional spacetime)

Comment: I assumed $d=4$ in the previous comment, but I think you get the idea

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Now, I am still not confident about applying the functional derivative, although the form is more familiar. My instinct is to write $- \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)} \int\phi(y)\partial_\mu(\delta(x-y))dy = -\int [ \frac{\delta \phi(y)}{\delta \phi(x)}\partial_\mu(\delta(x-y))+0]dy = -\int \delta(y-x)\partial_\mu(\delta(x-y))dy$. This appears to end up being the 4-derivative of unity which is zero. Is that right?

Comment: @Hannah in that expression, you are computing the functional derivative of $F_\mu(x)$ with respect of $\phi(x)$ (the arguments are the same), that's why it's weird. Try differentiating $F_\mu(x)$ wrt $\phi(z)$. You are on the right path though!

Comment: Also, i should add that this will lead to the derivative in position space. Another possibility would be to compute the derivative in momentum space if that's applicable to the situation you're dealing with

Comment: In that case I get $-\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(z)}\int\phi(y)\partial_\mu\delta(x-y)dy = -\int\delta(y-z)\partial_\mu\delta(x-y)dy=-\partial_\mu\delta(x-z)$. Is it generally true that one should compute the functional derivative with respect to a different argument? If so why? I'm having trouble finding clear answers in my reference texts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134601/discussion-between-nickolas-alves-and-hannah).

Comment: @Hannah I've added our comment discussions to the main answer. It might be clearer now.